# How can I type to a Minecraft Server Console w/ Python without actually typing?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, minecraft, pywin32

I'm setting up a method to control a Minecraft server through a Discord bot, I'm doing this because I'm hosting a server for my friend as my PC is quite powerful. I've set it up so they can send a command and get a screenshot of the window with some pywin32 hijinkery. Is there a way that I can set it up so through a Python command they can send a command to the console? I don't want the console to have to be tabbed in, nor the computer actually type anything.

The console is just a little command prompt, so I'm sure it's possible; I just don't know exactly how. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at using RCON [with MCTools](https://mctools.readthedocs.io/en/master/rcon.html) which can do it from another pc/server/ip if are using a hosting provider for the bot

Make sure your password is secure, ports are open(if doing it from an external device) and not to give it out to people who shouldn't have access to it.

To try it out in the browser you can use [a web client](https://cmsminecraftshop.com/en/console/)